# Some questions on laptop battery

Tags: windows, laptop, battery-life

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is it that kills laptop batteries?](https://superuser.com/questions/77457/what-is-it-that-kills-laptop-batteries)
>   [Do newer laptop batteries still need to be drained before recharging?](https://superuser.com/questions/41073/do-newer-laptop-batteries-still-need-to-be-drained-before-recharging)
>   [Is it better to use laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

I have found some laptop battery myths in here: http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html
But I have a few more questions so that I can ensure that my battery will last longer.

1. Do I really need to drain the battery for up to 10% and below if the laptop is new? Or can I charge it immediately on first use
2. What if I charge the battery to about 25% then there's a sudden blackout and I'm not able to continue the charge would it decrease the lifespan of the battery?
3. Does turning off the laptop while charging decreases  its lifespan?
4. Do I always need to full charge the laptop?
5. Is there any application for windows that would deactivate windows aero and other battery draining features of the windows 7 OS when the laptop is not plugged in. And activates it when plugged in?
6. Is battery care effective? http://batterycare.net/en/download.html
7. Is it ok to interrupt laptop charging? For example, I'm at 20% charge, but then I need to move places, then continue charging again.

Comment: most of this has been answered multiple times....also 1 question at a time plz

Comment: Also dupes: http://superuser.com/questions/136397/battery-on-or-off-while-running-the-laptop-on-electricity http://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged  http://superuser.com/questions/41073/do-newer-laptop-batteries-still-need-to-be-drained-before-recharging http://superuser.com/questions/152295/when-to-use-laptop-battery http://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power Could go on & on. Just visit the related questions links

Comment: And make sure you know what type of battery you have

Comment: Life is too short, just use your Notebook and enjoy it. 1-7, No.

Comment: @Moab, I guess that would be a Yes for 7! ;-)

Comment: oops, missed that one, 7 = yes