# Charging the laptop's battery during some heavy workload

Tags: laptop, battery-life

When you have the battery in and the charger plugged in and you have some heavy load (gaming for example), which is safe for as much as possible longer battery lifespan? Charger plugged in along with the battery or leave the battery out? And if the battery is not detachable, what is the best scenario in this case?

Comment: Check this http://superuser.com/questions/221104/some-questions-on-laptop-battery

Comment: @narzan Thank you but it does not answer my question. I'm talking about the case where the charger plugged in along with the battery.

Comment: Depends on the hardware configuration, and especially on the effectiveness of cooling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple correct answer to this question - the key elements and problems are as follows:

When the system is under load it is drawing more power.  This puts more strain on the battery.  Charging it under these conditions requires the battery to handle even more stress and thus hastens its demise (and if its a bad battery, sometimes spectacularly due to thermal runaway when the battery gets to hot).  Thus from a batteries POV you are better off not having it left in when working at load.

Unfortunately the battery serves to smoothe and provide "short bursts" of power, and protect the system.  If you run a laptop without a battery installed, you are more likely to fry the electronics and have random glitches due to less consistent power - so - particularly when a system is under heavy load, a battery is particularly useful.

The best case scenario would be to try and cool the laptop as well as possible - maybe using extra fans (heat is closely correlated with battery stress and death) - but if you can reduce the cpu/gpu demands (eg playing games at a lower resolution/framerate), that might help.   Similarly, using games written to take advantage of systems optimization helps (eg if video playing can be offloaded to the graphics card, it will use a lot less power then using the CPU - which in practice means use the latest drivers).

If the battery is not detachable, expect the battery to die sooner then it otherwise would.   (You could look at underclocking the CPU and/or GPU which will reduce heat and performance, but that might stuff up your game-play experience)

Answer (score -1):

*Hi,When you Charging the laptop so battery having high temperatures, due to heavy workload, But you can manage it, By Operating temperatures can have a big impact on battery life,**[For How to Take Care of Your Laptop Battery the Right Way](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-take-care-of-your-laptop-battery-the-right-way-1588054667*)**.